# Razor: adding an @if inside a tag - Then setting an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

```
<tr @if (-- condition --){id="x"}>
```

I know the above line probably makes no sense. But this is just to illustrate the sort of thing I would like to happen.

Using razor: How would i set the id attribute based on a condition. This reason for this is, I would like certain rows to be collapsible, and others not based on the condition in the if. I would then use jQuery to collapse toggle the required rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr @((-- condition --)?"id='x'":"") >
```

---

sample with if

```
 @if(test>1){
     <span>@test</span>
    }
    else{
     <span></span>
    }
```

---

The code above is written in a different way

```
@((test>1)?"<span>"+test+"</span>":"<span></span>")
```

Comment: It's saying the @ is an unexpected token

Comment: open  the parentheses after @ and close it at the end